# If the null space contains only the zero vector, the map is one-to-one

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces, matrix-equations

> How does finding out if the null space has only the zero vector prove one-to-one?

One-to-one means that there are distinct images for each distinct vector input.

$$\mathbb R^n \to \mathbb R^m$$

For each distinct vector in $\mathbb R^n$ we have a distinct vector in $\mathbb R^m$.

If we use Reduced row echelon form to solve a matrix A and each $x=(x_1,x_2,...x_n)$ equals $0$, then that shows that there is a unique solution, and that we have a linearly independence.

With what I know I am not making the connection here.

Comment: Hint: use linearity. Suppose two different vectors have the same image under a linear transformation. Then what's true of the image of their difference? (The other direction is easy too. If the nullspace of a matrix is nontrivial, then the image of the zero vector and a nonzero vector must be the same!)

Comment: they equal 0....still not making the connection on how getting the reduced row echelon form and seeing if the null space equals 0 relates.

Comment: Okay so my book says if T(w) does not equal T(0)=0 then we have one-to-one because only one distinct vector input of 0 should spit out an image of 0 if w is a non-zero vector. By getting the reduced row echelon form we are verifying that the only way to have T(0)=0 is by having each x={x1,x2,..,xn} equal 0. 

But why is it enough to prove that for the zero vector as an input do we have a distinct image for it? What about any other non-zero vector as input and a corresponding non-zero image? For us to have one-to-one it says that every distinct input vector must have a distinct image.

Comment: Spit-balling here. Okay so if we do not have x1=x2=...=xn=0 for each x, then we have free variable(s) which means that more than one possible solution exists for 0. Is that it?

Answer (score 3):

If $f(v)=f(w)$ then $f(v-w)=0$, so $v-w=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Look at this it may help. It is proven by using contradiction as

Suppose that $v_1 \neq 0_v$ were in $N(A)$, then $Av_1= 0_w$. Also, $A(0_v)=0_w$, hence, since $v1 \neq 0_v$, A is not one to one.

By assumption $N(A)=0_v$. If $v_1 \neq v_2$ then $v_1-v_2 \neq 0_v$, consequently $0_w \neq A(v_1 -v_2)=Av_1 -Av_2$. In other words, $v1 \neq v2$ implies that $A v_1 \neq Av_2$, i.e., A is one to one.

(The book is A second course on linear systems by C.A. Desoer)